# Who first noticed that Stirling numbers of the second kind count partitions?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview

When the Stirling numbers of the second kind were introduced by James Stirling in 1730, it was not combinatorially; rather, the numbers ${n \brace k}$ were defined via the polynomial identity
$$
x^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \brace k} x(x-1)\ldots (x-(k-1)). ~~(\star)
$$
Most modern treatments of the Stirling numbers introduce ${n \brace k}$ combinatorially, as the number of ways of partitioning a set of size $n$ into $k$ non-empty blocks, and then (combinatorially) derive identities such as ($\star$).

While preparing for some upcoming talks on topics related to Stirling numbers, I realized that I have no idea who it was who first observed that the numbers ${n \brace k}$ defined by ($\star$) have a combinatorial interpretation.

The earliest reference I can find is in W. Stevens, Significance of Grouping, Annals of Eugenics volume 8 (1937), pages 57--69 (available at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1937.tb02160.x/abstract). This seems to predate any mention of ``Stirling numbers of the second kind'' on MathSciNet.

I imagine that this is a question that has been thoroughly researched --- does anyone know of a reference?

Comment: Mathematical Reviews (the name for MathSciNet before it became a website) started in 1940, so it's not a surprise that anything from 1937 will predate (not just seem to predate) the written reviews you'll find on MathSciNet. It's also not a surprise that you'd like to avoid citing a journal on eugenics from the late 1930s.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Niels Nielsen,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Nielsen_(mathematician)) who coined the name "Stirling number of the second kind", gives the partition counting interpretation in his 1904 book [Handbuch der Theorie der Gammafunktion](https://archive.org/details/handbuchgamma00nielrich), page 70.

Answer (score 22):

There is a discussion of this question in Section 4 of P. Stein, A brief history of enumeration, in *Science and Computers* (G.-C. Rota, ed.), Academic Press, pp. 169-206. According to Stein, "$\dots$ the earliest reference I have been able to find for this basic distribution problem is Whitworth's *Choice and Chance* (5th edition, 1901) $\dots$." Stein points out that Whitworth was using a definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind different from  (but equivalent to) Stirling's and that "it is virtually certain that Whitworth did not recognize the identity of [the two definitions]."

Comment: Thanks! I looked at Whitworth's book, and found that he discusses the problem already in the 2nd ed. (1870). On p. 173, he proves that "the number of ways in which $n$ different things can be distributed into $r$ indifferent parcels, with no blank lots, is $n!$ times the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $((e^x-1)^r)/r!$". A scan is available [here](https://archive.org/details/choicechance00whitrich). I can't find the 1st ed. (1867), but the problem is unlikely to appear there: in the preface, Whitworth says that the chapter in which the problem is presented is new to the 2nd ed..

Comment: @David. Interesting. Thanks for checking this.

Answer (score 4):

Donald E. Knuth in the second part of his article *Two Notes on Notation* details some of the research he did on Stirling numbers and their history. He also introduces interesting notational conventions linking binomial coefficients and Stirling numbers:

$\binom{n+1}{k}$ = $\binom{n}{k}$ + $\binom{n}{k-1}$

$\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n+1}{k}$ = $n\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$ + $\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k-1}$

$\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n+1}{k}$ = $k\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$ + $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k-1}$

where

$\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$ = the number of permutations of n objects having k cycles

$\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$ = the number of partitions of n objects into k nonempty subsets

A copy of the article is available at:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211.pdf

The answer is in the article at page 12 where Knuth mentions that : "Christian Kramp [28] proved near the end of the eighteenth century that ... "

[28] Christian Kramp, “Coefficient des allgemeinen Gliedes jeder willkührlichen Potenz eines Infinitinomiums; Verhalten zwischen Coefficienten der Gleichungen und Summen der Produkte und der Potenzen ihrer Wurzeln; Transformationen und Substitution der Reihen durcheinander”,
in *Der polynomische Lehrsatz*, edited by Carl Friedrich Hindenburg (Leipzig, 1796), 91–122.

Comment: Knuth's article is very nice but it doesn't seem to address David Galvin's question.